# How to sum integers and convert this to time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have a playlist with has_many tracks. Each track have time duration as integer in milliseconds.
I want count total time duration for playlist. Actually i make something like this from my playlist model:

```
  def total_tracks_duration
    seconds = tracks.sum(:duration) / 1000
    Time.at(seconds).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
```

Playlist spec:

```
it '#total_tracks_duration' do
    play = build(:playlist)
    3.times do
        create(:track, playlist: play, duration: 60000)
    end

    expect(play.total_tracks_duration).to eq("00:03:00")
end
```

And finally i have got this failure:

```
    Failures:

  1) Playlist #total_tracks_duration
     Failure/Error: expect(play.total_tracks_duration).to eq("00:03:00")

       expected: "00:03:00"
            got: "01:00:00"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/playlist_spec.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.69605 seconds (files took 9.83 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Where i make mistake?

Comment: Personally I don't think `Time#at` is the correct route here as the result would depend on TZ settings etc.-why not just use math? As to why you're not getting the expected 3m part, I don't know-that part works fine for me. Are you sure you have no other tracks created at the time of this spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's adding an offset for your timezone (UTC+1), so simply do

`Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

and it should work :)